# Calculate the days between dates from a grouped data.frame R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate the number of days between rows of a data.frame groped by a couple of fields, so if I have the following data.frame:

```
da <- read.table(text="i     j  data date     
 2   682   147 2008-05-26
 2   682   317 2010-11-13
 2   682   217 2019-08-05
 3   682   147 2008-05-26
 3   682   317 2010-11-13
10   682   220 2019-08-08", header=TRUE)
require(dplyr)
da %>% count(i,j)
```

I would like to calculate two periods for the first group, 1 period for the second, and none for the last.

I can calculate the intervals between the first and last dates

```
require(lubridate)

da %>% group_by(i,j) %>% 
    summarize(fini=ymd(min(date)),fend=ymd(max(date)),deltaD=as.numeric(fend - fini)) 

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'i' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   i [3]
      i     j fini       fend       deltaD
  <int> <int> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
1     2   682 2008-05-26 2019-08-05   4088
2     3   682 2008-05-26 2010-11-13    901
3    10   682 2019-08-08 2019-08-08      0
```

that is fine if I have two rows in the group, but I can't figure out how to do it if I have 3 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)

da %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  arrange(i, j, date) %>%
  group_by(i, j) %>%
  transmute(fini = date, fend = lead(date), deltaD = as.numeric(fend - fini)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ungroup

#      i     j fini       fend       deltaD
#  <int> <int> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
#1     2   682 2008-05-26 2010-11-13    901
#2     2   682 2010-11-13 2019-08-05   3187
#3     3   682 2008-05-26 2010-11-13    901
```

Comment: With a small correction it works `deltaD = as.numeric(fend - fini)`

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work. I used `lead` (after `arrange` to order by date), and some tweaks to avoid dropping groups with only one date

```
da %>% 
  group_by(i,j) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(date) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(lead_date = dplyr::lead(date),
                one_in_group = n() == 1) %>% # to maintain row with i = 10
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(lead_date) | one_in_group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(lead_date = ifelse(one_in_group, date, lead_date),# handles solo dates
                date = lubridate::ymd(date),
                lead_date = lubridate::ymd(lead_date),
                deltaD = as.numeric(lead_date - date)) %>%
  dplyr::select(- one_in_group) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(i, j, date)

# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   i, j [3]
      i     j  data date       lead_date  deltaD
  <int> <int> <int> <date>     <date>      <dbl>
1     2   682   147 2008-05-26 2010-11-13    901
2     2   682   317 2010-11-13 2019-08-05   3187
3     3   682   147 2008-05-26 2010-11-13    901
4    10   682   220 2019-08-08 2019-08-08      0
```